# I have a problem running Foundation Watch (gulp error) - /_input-group.scss

Tags: zurb-foundation, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

The compile fails because of the error:

```
Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    node_modules\foundation-sites\scss\forms\_input-group.scss
Error: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'rem*rem'.
        on line 25 of node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/forms/_input-group.scss, in mixin `foundation-form-prepostfix`
        from line 30 of node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/forms/_forms.scss, in mixin `foundation-forms`
        from line 14 of scss/app.scss
>   $height: ($input-font-size * $input-line-height) + (get-side($input-paddin
   -----------^
```

I use the input-group features in login and sign forms and can't afford to not include the foundation-forms; in my app.scss file. This problem arised when i switched from win 7 to win 10.

Comment: What does you gulpfile look like? What is the command you are running that causes that error to be thrown?

Comment: Changed quote to code block for better readability

Comment: Please try renaming node_modules and reinstall the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers but I have already found the solution. I updated the _input-group.scss file. See below.

From

$height: ($input-font-size * $input-line-height) + (get-side($input-padding, 'top') + get-side($input-padding, 'bottom')) - rem-calc(1);

to

$height: ($input-font-size + $form-spacing * 1.5);

---

Best regards,
Jure